# How to pass custom amount to In App Purchase in iOS application

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am working on Xamarin App. In this application, I have many celebrities, a user can send a request to celebrities for creating a video for some occasion and will pay some amount we have set for celebrity. The amount for celebrity can be anything and the number of celebrities could be too many so in In App Purchase we can create tiers but it is not possible to create and use 1000 0r 10000 price tiers and use them so simply I want the way where I will just pass my amount it will be deducted. Is it possible? Is there any workaround? For better understand, you can see the "cameo.com" site. I have checked their iOS app and they have implemented such a solution. they have different amounts for different celebrities and it is paid by apple in-app purchase. can anyone help me with this challenge? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not possible. *"they have different amounts for different celebrities"* - then they have created multiple in-app-purchases, each with a specific amount. There is no mechanism that allows passing in an arbitrary amount. You present it to the user however you want, but to the store, you have to send one of the in-app-purchases that you have predefined as per Apple's instructions. **Maybe** you can "fake" arbitrary amounts, by sending a *combination* of pre-defined purchases.  E.g. $1, $2, $4, $8, etc could form any $$ amount by comination.

Comment: I assume they use Apple Pay or similar payment providers. Depending on the content/use case of you app, Apple allows you to use third party payments instead of IAPs. This could also be a solution for your use case or you introduce an in-app currency. So, user can buy 50, 100, 500 or whatever amount you want of in-app-coins and spend as much as they like on the celebrities.